# How to log how much time a user been playing with game console?

Tags: cross-platform, pc, xbox, playstation4

I want to create a solution for game centers which they own different game consoles, is there any way to log each user playing time and gather all of this info into a pc? if yes how is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "game centers" ? As in a gaming event?

Comment: no in my country there are some places that people come to play video games. there are like 10 game console which you go and play for certain time, like arcade ....

Comment: If the available consoles are the popular consoles (xbox, playstation etc) then there is no easy way to do that. You can maybe implement a "log in" feature, similar to how internet cafes do for PCs, which sounds time-consuming. My experience on the subject is not that great, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot effectively get this information from the consoles themselves in an automated fashion (with consumer console hardware).

If you require that all users sign in to accounts controlled by your business, you could monitor play time for games yourself by logging in to that account as well. But you're mostly out of luck, here.

---

Given your stated use-case in the comments (a net cafe), I'd argue that time spent *playing a game* isn't what you want anyway: you want to know how much time they're *sitting in the seat*, regardless of whether or not they ever touch the console there.

To that end, I think a lower-tech method of time tracking is probably your best bet.

Comment: that's really great idea! i didn't thought is that way, log the time they spending seating on chair. brilliant!